# Loading postgresql table to spark SyntaxError

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

the following code is reading a table from my postgresql database, and I'm following the directives I've read on the internet:

```
val txs = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
("driver" -> "org.postgresql.Driver"),
("url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://host/dbname"),
("dbtable" -> "(select field1 from t) as table1"),
("user" -> "username"),
("password" -> "password"))).load()
```

I'm running this query on a jupyter notebook but I'm getting the SyntaxError as message but no clue about the stacktrace. I'm assuming that query was right as I saw similar queries working with other people. Any help is appreciate to try to understand how to fix this issue.

This is the error I get from my notebook:
[image]

Comment: @zero323 I'm using the Scala Three kernel indeed. I just got Name: Syntax Error, Message and StackTrace are both blanks so I have no clue what can be the source of this error. Just add the screenshot of what I'm getting

Comment: Huh... Query alone looks valid so it is most likely a bug. Can you add Toree version?

Comment: Seems to work just fine on the current build.

Comment: @zero323 I'm using toree-0.2.0.dev1.tar.gz Did you do the test? What version did u use?

Comment: The same, but these are nightly builds so there is no guarantee we use the same. Just to be sure there is no other issue - does it work with plain `spark-shell`?

Comment: @zero323 it worked at my local machine `spark-shell` fine, just frustrated with the notebook results.

Comment: @zero323 would you mind if you provided the command(s) you used to install the Toree in your jupyter notebook?

Comment: `pip install https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/incubator/toree/0.2.0/snapshots/dev1/toree-pip/toree-0.2.0.dev1.tar.gz` followed by `jupyter toree install  --spark_home ~/Spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7 --user --interpreters=Scala,PySpark,SparkR,SQL`. All with Anaconda, Python 3.5.